# JS получить прогресс загрузки файла из PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Пытаюсь отобразить процент загрузки файлов, которые загружаю через GET метод.
При переходе по ссылке http://site/updates/ загружаются файлы из массива, код php:

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/public/updates/".$fileName);
        file_put_contents ('C:\\'.$fileName, $file);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как через js запустить переход по ссылке и процесс загрузки файлов в элементе #progress ?

Comment: Так не получится. Читайте документацию по загрузке файлов или читайте также про `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @And может возможно как то передать callback в js ?

Comment: Вы видимо не понимаете, что делаете. Прогресс загрузки можно отследить лишь только через сессии или через `XMLHttpRequest`. Что не понятного?

Comment: @And может у Вас есть пример варианта загрузки на js ?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress

Comment: "файлов, которые загружаю через GET метод" - насколько я знаю GET метод имеет ограничение по длине строки и большие файлы через него не передать. Я бы поступил проще - вначале бы срипт php вернул бы имена файлов в json массиве, после этого javascript отправлял бы команды на перекачку каждого этого файла(можно передавать id файлов) и по завершении каждой операции - изменялся бы прогресс бар - общее количество мы то уже знаем - я так реализовывал коммерческие проекты